# Legend markers appear several times

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, marker

I need to plot data sites on a map. For example, survey "DEPROAS" has five stations so, I need to plot'em and insert it in legend guide. But, when I do this, instead of plotting just once (representative of these five stations), It plots five[image] dots. Any idea? Figure and code below.

```
            #### DEPROAS #### - Cabo Frio

            fcf1=[-22-(59.030/60),-42-(07.340/60)]
            fcf2=[-23-(05.444/60),-41-(54.700/60)]
            fcf=[fcf1,fcf2]
            fcf=np.array(fcf)
            lat_fcf = fcf[0:len(fcf),0]
            lon_fcf = fcf[0:len(fcf),1]
            x_fcf,y_fcf=m(lon_fcf,lat_fcf)

            plt.plot(x_fcf[0],y_fcf[0], 'o', label='DEPROAS', color='#88ff4d', zorder = 3000)
            plt.plot(x_fcf[1],y_fcf[1], 'o', label='DEPROAS', color='#88ff4d', zorder = 3000)

            #### DEPROAS #### - Ubatuba
            fub1=[-23-(43.560/60),-44-(53.860/60)]
            fub2=[-24-(04.028/60),-44-(39.005/60)]  ##rever nos dados no lab
            fub=[fub1,fub2]
            fub=np.array(fub)
            lat_fub = fub[0:len(fub),0]
            lon_fub = fub[0:len(fub),1]
            x_fub,y_fub=m(lon_fub,lat_fub)

            plt.plot(x_fub[0],y_fub[0], 'o', label = 'DEPROAS', color='#88ff4d', zorder = 3000)
            plt.plot(x_fub[1],y_fub[1], 'o', label = 'DEPROAS', color='#88ff4d', zorder = 3000)

            #### DEPROAS #### - Guanabara

            fbg1=[-23-(18.34/60),-42-(45.81/60)]
            fbg=[fbg1]
            fbg=np.array(fbg)
            lat_fbg = fbg[0:len(fbg),0]
            lon_fbg = fbg[0:len(fbg),1]
            x_fbg,y_fbg=m(lon_fbg,lat_fbg)

            plt.plot(x_fbg[0],y_fbg[0], 'o', label = 'DEPROAS', color='#88ff4d', zorder = 3000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You plot 5 series with label "DEPROAS" therefore your legend has 5 entries of all these markers and labels.

According to [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) you have to construct custom legend and put all desired series to a list and plot it in a legend:

```
...
series1, = plt.plot(x_fub[0],y_fub[0], 'o', label = 'DEPROAS', color='#88ff4d', zorder = 3000)
plt.plot(x_fub[1],y_fub[1], 'o', label = 'DEPROAS', color='#88ff4d', zorder = 3000)

# make custom legend for series1
plt.legend(handles=[series1], loc=2)
...
```